# Joe Blow pump extra parts

Tags: maintenance

anyone know where or how I can get a rubber insert for either presta or schrader head on my joe blow max floor pump? Just bought it and schrader head did NOT have an insert so it won't grab the valve. Is this a Topeak product? Would Topeak send me one??
Mike
Cambridge, MA

Comment: Have you tried Google?  Eg: http://www.topeak.com/products/Pumps/JoeBlowSport, near the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 3):

A good bike shop that is a Topeak dealer will likely have parts for the pump. You can visit the [Topeak: Where to Buy](http://www.topeak.com/WhereToBuy) page to find dealers in your area. Or contact [Customer Service](http://www.topeak.com/Service/usa_customer_service) - they may just send you the parts for a minimal shipping charge or free; other companies have done that for me in the past.